# Managing IPTables with API pref. php

Tags: php, api, router, iptables

Is there an API so I can manage IPTables with PHP, it's for a project to build a router with a browser login, kinda the same as a Fonera?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may solve your problem.  The tricky part is sudo for apache process and tracking, rest is standard php and iptables:

http://www.andybev.com/index.php/Using_iptables_and_PHP_to_create_a_captive_portal

Answer (score 1):

I think easiest way would be to use exec() for firing IPtables commands. Maybe use your PHP to create a script and then execute that in the end. I don't think there is an "API" to control IPtables only the executable in a lot Linux Distributions.

Comment: Running PHP as root through a web interface.. ugh.

Comment: I was not saying he should run it as root. An idea to avoid that could be to make the rules. Validate them. Put them somewhere on the file system and let cron or something else handle the root stuff. Still fishy but better than running PHP as root.

Comment: I was thinking about that too but you would have to flush and re-enter a lot every time something changes / someone logs on.'Basically rebuilding the entire rule set (if I'm not mistaken)

@ThiefMaster I know, securitywise 'ugh' is an understatement but do a choice? Dont know if it is possible to create a user for just iptables.

Comment: You could also take a look at webmin and how they do it. As far as I know they have IPtables management support.

Comment: I looked it up, it's the module 'firewall', they use cgi with perl to build up the tables and write them to /etc/iptables.up.rules so that would be an option but not ideal when you try to build a system that can automatically administer the rules based on user login

Comment: I guess there isn't a away around using exec() and running it with raised privileges.

Comment: The problem with PHP is that **all** exec-style functions only take a string for the command+args. So there's always the risk of shell command injection. When using e.g. python you could use methods which take the command+args as a list - i.e. no injection of bad things is possible.

Comment: @Thiefmaster there are system, escapeshellcmd and passthru for to manage that.

Comment: Yes, and it'e easy to forget it...

Comment: Little work-around would be to let php send the data to python and then to the iptables

Answer (score 1):

You can install [rfw](https://github.com/securitykiss-com/rfw) which is the REST API for iptables and runs as a server with root privileges. Clients can use any HTTP API without special rights, so you can use curl from PHP to send commands to rfw.

Sample command:

```
PUT /drop/input/eth0/11.22.33.44
```

which corresponds to:

```
iptables -I INPUT -i eth0 -s 11.22.33.44 -j DROP
```

Disclaimer: I started that project.

Comment: Very cool project! I love your license.txt ;)

Comment: Feel free to copy. The license itself is also MIT licensed. I hope to live long enough to see the day when all this licensing absurd is not needed.